# Which jQuery libary should i include in my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my website i have few jquery because i have a few funcions (sticky header, anchors and animations). I want to know is it neccessery to include all of it or i can include only one or two ?

**Here is my included jquerys**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There should be single instance of the jQuey on page. Probably use latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include the following:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.7.2.js"></script>
```

This configuration will only support IE9+

---

If you need IE7 or IE8, use:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.7.2.js"></script>
```